# Mongo DB - Filter specific nested object array

Tags: mongodb

I have the following Mongo structure

```
{
    "brand": "test",
    "keyword": "test",
    "user": "test",
    "link": "AAA",
    "text": "test",
    "insert_utc_ts": "2021-11-04 23:18:34.970",
    "update_utc_ts": "2021-11-04 23:45:55.561",
    "media": [{
        "src": "Test2",
        "media_ai_text": "Test",
        "media_type": "PHOTO_TEST",
        "insert_utc_ts": "2021-11-04 23:23:30.315",
        "update_utc_ts": "2021-11-04 23:23:30.315"
    }, {
        "src": "Test",
        "media_ai_text": "Test",
        "media_type": "PHOTO_TEST",
        "insert_utc_ts": "2021-11-04 23:23:45.331",
        "update_utc_ts": "2021-11-04 23:23:45.331"
    }]
}
```

I need to find the Media update_utc_ts where **media.src = Test2 and link = AAA**

I've tried to use this filter

```
{ link: "AAA", media.src: "Test2"}
```

But it's not working at all.
Any help is appreciated
Thx

Comment: Did you try `{ link: "AAA", "media.src": "Test2"}`?

Comment: yes but not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$unwind` to deconstruct the array and then `$match` by your desired value. And optional stage `$project` to return only the value you want:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$media"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "link": "AAA",
      "media.src": "Test2"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "media.update_utc_ts": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RLBw5175JS9)

Note that I'm assuming you want to retrieve `media.update_utc_ts` and that's why your filter query doesn't work.

Comment: Thx, my problem is that I'm using a RobotFramework library, and I'm not able to use all mongo funtion/syntax. I was hoping to have a single "find" query including media.src and the link. it is possible?

Comment: Maybe `$elemMatch` into projection stage can helps you [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YEraY7xukBx) but it only returns the first coincidence.